# Use jQuery to reach a specific span-element and check its classes

Tags: jquery, html

I need to figure out if the span-element with the class `glyphicon-user` has also the class hidden or not.

In the sourcecode sometimes it is hidden and sometimes it isn't - in this case the `glyphicon-asterisk` is hidden. Also the numbers which the ids contains are random.

I am using tampermonkey to manipulate with jquery.

The source (cleaned up):

```
<div id="list">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <span id="one_98762356" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                <span id="two_98762356" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk hidden"></span>
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <span id="one_98412447" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user hidden"></span>
                <span id="two_98412447" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

What i tried so far:

```
$('#list > div').each(function() {
    panel = $(this).find("div:first"); //needs to be reused in the further code

    // 1st try
    if(panel.find("div > span:nth-child(2)").is(".glyphicon-asterisk, .hidden")){
        //do something
    }

    // 2nd try
    if(panel.find("div > span:first").hasClass("glyphicon-user") && panel.find("div > span:first").is(":visible")){
        //do something
    }

    //too many other trys ...
});
```

I am a bit dubious about my way to reach the span i want.
Also the difficulty is `glyphicon-user` is in every "pack" so i just need to figure out if it's visible or has the class hidden or whatelse.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the span have to be within a div, or can it be anywhere as long as it has the `glyphicon-user` class?

Comment: Thats the code i used to work with. I can not change or switch any containers.

Comment: I think you can get all `glyphicon` classes and check each one with `hasClass('hidden')` function.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou do you have an example?

Comment: @GePu you want to check which `glyphicon` class has also other classes assigned like `class="glyphicon hidden" or "glyphicon visible"` ?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Jepp thats correct. It tried `.is(".glyphicon-asterisk, .hidden")` which is not working, somehow. (since i need `glyphicon-user` visible `glyphicon-asterik` needs to be hidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added all `.glyphicon` class element in array and then iterate each element and check which one has also the `.hidden` class. Then you can `toggleClass()` with `.visible`

```js
let glyphs_arr = $(".glyphicon");

glyphs_arr.each(function(index, element){
     if($(element).hasClass('glyphicon-user')){
          $(element).parents().addClass('visible');
     }else if($(element).hasClass('glyphicon-asterisk')){
        $(element).parents().addClass('hidden');
         
     }
});
```

```css
.hidden{ display:none;}
.visible { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <span id="one_98762356" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user visible">User</span>
                <span id="two_98762356" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk hidden">Asterisk</span>
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <span id="one_98412447" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user hidden">User</span>
                <span id="two_98412447" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk visible">Asterisk</span>
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to know in which element i am. For this i have the `panel` variable. Then i add my own class (or your hidden) to the specific panel to hide it. In your solution i don't know where i am. Or tbh i don't know whats inside of `let glyphs_arr = $(".glyphicon");`.

Comment: @GePu all span elements have the same class `glyphicon` so the array has all the elements with the same class name. So you need to iterate each element and check which one has also `glyphicon-user` or `glyphicon-asterisk` to add `visible` or `hidden` class.

Comment: @GePu so do you want to add `visible` or `hidden` class? if yes then the span tag must have only `class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" or "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"`

Comment: Okay i understand. Which element is hidden? Is it the span? Because i need to hide the first div (see `panel` variable) where the span is inside. I Think to use parent, parent, parent might be the most wrong solution :-/

Comment: @GePu no it will be very confusing. Just check the span tag if it has class `glyphicon-user` and then add the `visible` class. And `glyphicon-asterisk` add `hidden`

Comment: I think i need to clean something up: between the `div` elements there is way more text and other (non `span`) elements. So to only hide the `span` element is not very useful for mir. I need to hide the complete container (first `div` under `id="list"`)

Comment: @GePu my answer is helpful?

Comment: I got it working with `$(element).parents().addClass("hidden");`. So yes, i think its answered. Thank you.